# "Cannot create a win event notifier without a QEventDispatcherWin32"

Tags: qt, qextserialport

Qt triggers the exception
`"Cannot create a win event notifier without a QEventDispatcherWin32"`
when trying to open a QextSerialPort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was beause I was inadvertently using a debug build of qextserialport.dll with a release build of my host application.